# Auto loading when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have this script to make a new ajax call when the user scroll down. But how to make it to do it once. Since if the user scroll to fast they are **n** ajax calls with the same data.

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){

            whenTo=$(window).scrollTop();

        if(whenTo>=($(document).height()-($(window).height())-600)){
// make ajax call
}


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding in a boolean value that checks if it has already been done?

for example:

```
var hasLoaded = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){

        whenTo=$(window).scrollTop();

        if(!hasLoaded && (whenTo>=($(document).height()-($(window).height())-600))){
            hasLoaded = true;
            // make ajax call
        }
});
```

Using this method means you can just change the variable to false whenever you like to allow the ajax to be called again if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Underscore.js, and [`_.throttle()`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) or [`_.debounce()`](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) – assuming you want to call the function repeatedly, or [`_.once()`](http://underscorejs.org/#once) if only once.